# Laravel "partial" seeding

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration, laravel-seeding

I'm wondering how I am supposed to handle "partial" seeding.

Example, I have a "settings" table for the applications settings and these are populated on the initial seed, and down the road I need to add new settings. Is there a way to seed new data into the database or can seeding only be done on a fresh database?

If the latter, would the correct way to do this be to populate data through a migration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [`--class`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding#running-seeders) option to seed only settings, for example:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=SettingsTableSeeder
```